# .replace in Javascript to replace multiple characters

Tags: extendscript

```
         var layerName = layer.name;
         //replace weird characters in layer names
         var layerName = layerName.replace(")", "-");
         var layerName = layerName.replace("(", "-");
         var layerName = layerName.replace(":", "-");
         var layerName = layerName.replace(":", "-");
         var layerName = layerName.replace(/\//, "-");
         var layerName = layerName.replace('/', "");
         var layerName = layerName.replace("---", "-");
         var layerName = layerName.replace("--", "-");
         var file = new File(folder.fsName+"/"+layerName+".png");
```

using extendscript but for some reason it wont replace two "--" characters. I feel like I could do this easier with regex but I suck at those. am trying to replace all weird non alpha-numeric char and spaces with "-"

Comment: you only need to declare the layerName variable once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
// Test String
var layerName = "123---A%*^%   )()H";
layerName
     .replace(/\-+/g,'-')  // Collapse multiple dashes into a single one 
     .replace(/\W+/g,'-'); // Replace Non-word characters
```

Result:

```
123-A-H
```

`\W+` Matches all non-word characters,

Comment: this worked perfect. thanks! I will have to start diving into regex a lot more.

Comment: You're welcome, heres a quick link for regexes, I learned a lot in that website [Regular Expresions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Answer (score 0):

The regex you want is:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9]
```

and your replace character is '-'

Comment: like this? var layerName = layerName.replace("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "-"); it doesn't seem to work